# $_POST Not Showing Current Option

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

My code is meant to take input text and generate an output for it using PHP via AJAX. While `$_POST["inputText"]` is set `$_POST["style"]` isn't set. How can I modify my code to set `$_POST["style"]` to the current option (a, b or c)?

`functions01.php` is any generic PHP file that takes `$_POST["inputText"]` and `$_POST["style"]` echos out an appropriate output.

**foo1.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <body>
 <!-- Input -->
    <div class="form">
      <form onsubmit="makeRequest(); return false">
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="inputText">
        <select name="style">
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="c">C</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
 
    <br>
    
    <!-- Output -->
    <div class="txtBox">
      <textarea  id="txtBox">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    
    <!-- AJAX to create output using function01.php file-->
    <script>
        function makeRequest() {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();            
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {               
                document.getElementById("txtBox").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
            };
            httpRequest.open("POST", "functions01.php", true);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpRequest.send("inputText=" + document.getElementById("inputText").value);
        }
        
        //function 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<select name="style" id="ddlStyle">
```

JS

```
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("inputText").value;

  var e = document.getElementById("ddlStyle");
  var styleVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  ...
  httpRequest.send("inputText=" + inputVal + "&style=" +  styleVal );
```